# How can I store a byteArray in Adobe AIR local SQL?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, air

I can read an image from hard drive and get a ByteArray from its source. Is there any way to store those bytes in local SQL database? What datatype for this field I need to choose?

Or maybe there is a more clever way to save an Image file itself into AIR SQL?..

Answer (score 3):

[blog.affirmix.com/2009/01/28/getting-started-with-adobe-air-and-sqlite-and-avoiding-the-problems/](http://blog.affirmix.com/2009/01/28/getting-started-with-adobe-air-and-sqlite-and-avoiding-the-problems/)

Go to Blobs and Bitmaps... Talks about storing images in the SQLite Db provided by AIR

[www.peterelst.com/blog/2008/04/07/introduction-to-sqlite-in-adobe-air/](http://www.peterelst.com/blog/2008/04/07/introduction-to-sqlite-in-adobe-air/)

Go to  SQLite YouTube Database..